# Dynamic caption of an entry element

Tags: monotouch.dialog

I have created an element with Reflection API and give it a caption as:

```
[Caption("Book title"]
public string Title;
```

Is it possible to set the caption label programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing attribute value at runtime ?

```
   Caption[] attrs=(Caption[]) typeof(MyClass).
          GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Caption), false);
   attrs[0] = new Caption("New caption")
```

You'll probably have to reload your dialogviewcontroller's data.

Some docs on attributes :
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84326/attributes-of-c/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I finally accessed the section as DialogViewController.Root[0].Section = ".....";